# How to delete outputs from Google Colab notebooks without loading the Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

Whenever I open a specific Google Colaboratory notebook, on any web browser, before I even get the chance to click any options click "Disconnect and Restart Runtime", the notebook starts taking up so much ram on my local computer that my web browser is forced to crash the web page. My best guess was maybe one of the outputs, for whatever reason, is so large it takes up most the RAM on my computer, even though it should normally be limited in size to 5000 lines (I think), so I am honestly just baffled.

Any help in removing all non-code elements in the notebook would be greatly appreciated so I can continue using it.

(Currently I am unsure how to share the notebook with other users on stack overflow)

Comment: Update: When I added a link to the notebook in the question (I realised the link didn't work for other google accounts), then clicked on the link, I managed to load the notebook with no outputs. However, when I re-ran the code, specifically outputting a dictionary, the notebook crashed again, and I cannot replicate opening the notebook fresh.

Comment: I fixed to issue by sharing notebook with another google account